# Get angular degree difference between consequent rows

Tags: r, 360-degrees

I am struggling to design an efficient solution that run over `14*10e6  records` and that is able to assign each `element_id` the `difference` (`-`) against its previous `element_id`. Clearly, for each `element_id == 1` the delta is always equal to `NA` because it has no previous element to be compared to.

Considering a data.frame like the following:

```
set.seed(1234)
ID <- c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 5))
element_id <- c(seq.int(1, 6), seq.int(1, 5))
degree <- as.integer(runif(11, 0, 360))  #angular degrees goes from 0 to 359 because 0 is also 360.
mydf <- data.frame(ID, element_id, degree)
```

What differ this quesiton from other related to difference between consecutives rows is that if `element_id` `i` is equal `350` and the `element_id` `i+1` is equal to `10`, the difference should just be `20`.

Comment: @PoGibas thank you for the feedback but please be nice and polite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try function `getDifference()`. Function `getDifference()`:

1. Gets difference between two degrees
2. Add `180` to that difference
3. Get modulus of `360` (`%% 360`) and subtract `180`

Code:

```
# Function to calculate difference in degrees
getDifference <- function(degreeA = 0, degreeB = 0) {
    (degreeA - degreeB + 180) %% 360 - 180
}
# Test function
getDifference(10, 350)
# [1] 20
getDifference(350, 10)
# [1] -20
```

Apply to OPs data

```
# 1. Get difference with previous row (data.table shift)
# 2. For each ID is done using data.table by 
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)
mydf[, degreeDiff := getDifference(degree, shift(degree)), ID]

#    ID element_id degree degreeDiff
# 1:  1          1     40         NA
# 2:  1          2    224       -176
# 3:  1          3    219         -5
# 4:  1          4    224          5
# 5:  1          5    309         85
# 6:  1          6    230        -79
# 7:  2          1      3         NA
# 8:  2          2     83         80
# 9:  2          3    239        156
#10:  2          4    185        -54
#11:  2          5    249         64
```

Comment: thank you very much. What does `%%` mean? I think this is a nice solution. However, probably it is not extremely efficient on 14kk records `data.frame`

Comment: @Seymour data.table is efficient on large datasets, I assume you mean 14x10e6 rows, (kk doesn't ring much value for me)

Comment: You are right @Tensibai than you :) I misleadingly use kk becase 1k = 10e^3

Comment: @PoGibas Great answer! Thank you very much for your prompt reply

Comment: @Seymour then I usggest you use ISO suffixes: 10e6 is 1M, 10e9 1G, etc.

Comment: Often people use something like `atan2(sin(a2 - a1), cos(a2 - a1))` for angular differences (in radians), not sure if one is faster that the other.

Comment: @Axeman I don't understand much of trigonometry but what I need is to have how the direction changed from between different record in order to compute some kind of "variance/st. dev" with the objective of discover in which areas the wind change direction more than in other areas. Do you think I can reach the same objective using radians?

Comment: Then calculate the circular standard deviation. The `circular` package is really nice and can calculate means and variances etc. for circular data. I think you can even test for significance using the `wallraff.test`.